# Splunk REST API: How to set "Send to triggered alerts" action when creating an alert?

Tags: rest, splunk

I wish to create a Splunk alert using the REST API. However, I can't find the action "Send to triggered alerts" in the actions list. How can I add that action?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The parameter you are looking for in the [Splunk documentation](https://docs.splunk.com/Documentation/Splunk/latest/RESTREF/RESTsearch#saved.2Fsearches) is `alert.track`. You must set `alert.track` to `1` in your request.

Here is an example of such an alert:

```
curl -k -u admin:password https://some.address:8089/servicesNS/admin/search/saved/searches \
  -d name=test4 \
  --data-urlencode output_mode='json' \
  --data-urlencode actions='' \
  --data-urlencode alert.digest_mode='1' \
  --data-urlencode alert.expires='24h' \
  --data-urlencode alert.managedBy='' \
  --data-urlencode alert.severity='3' \
  --data-urlencode alert.suppress='0' \
  --data-urlencode alert.suppress.fields='' \
  --data-urlencode alert.suppress.period='' \
  --data-urlencode alert.track='1' \
  --data-urlencode alert_comparator='equal to' \
  --data-urlencode alert_condition='' \
  --data-urlencode alert_threshold='0' \
  --data-urlencode alert_type='number of events' \
  --data-urlencode allow_skew='0' \
  --data-urlencode cron_schedule='*/2 * * * *' \
  --data-urlencode description='' \
  --data-urlencode disabled='0' \
  --data-urlencode displayview='' \
  --data-urlencode is_scheduled='1' \
  --data-urlencode is_visible='1' \
  --data-urlencode max_concurrent='1' \
  --data-urlencode realtime_schedule='1' \
  --data-urlencode restart_on_searchpeer_add='1' \
  --data-urlencode run_n_times='0' \
  --data-urlencode run_on_startup='0' \
  --data-urlencode schedule_priority='default' \
  --data-urlencode schedule_window='0' \
  --data-urlencode search='sourcetype="auth" failed'
```